# Doxygen: return from list to normal paragraph

Tags: markdown, comments, doxygen

I have the code:

```
/**
 * Lists are usually preceded by a line ending in a colon:
 * - Item in the list.
 * - Another item.
 *   - key: Sub-list with keys, first item.
 *   - key2: (optional) Second item with a key.
 * - Back to the outer list. Sometimes list items are quite long, in which case
 *   you can wrap the text like this.
 * - Last item in the outer list.
 * Text that is outside of the list continues here.
 */
void main(void)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Doxygen generates for me:

[image: picture]

```
Lists are usually preceded by a line ending in a colon:
    - Item in the list.
    - Another item.
        - key: Sub-list with keys, first item.
        - key2: (optional) Second item with a key.
    - Back to the outer list. Sometimes list items are quite long, in which case
      you can wrap the text like this.
    - Last item in the outer list. Text that is outside of the list continues here.
```

I expect to get documentation like this:

```
Lists are usually preceded by a line ending in a colon:
    - Item in the list.
    - Another item.
        - key: Sub-list with keys, first item.
        - key2: (optional) Second item with a key.
    - Back to the outer list. Sometimes list items are quite long, in which case
      you can wrap the text like this.
    - Last item in the outer list.
Text that is outside of the list continues here.
```

The problem is in the last sentence ("Text that is ..."). **The first and last sentences must be indented equally**.

I can solve this issue by inserting an additional empty line. But this doesn't suit me. I need another solution.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.15 is a bit older, the current doxygen version is 1.10.0 (though for your problem this doesn't matter). To end the list you either need an empty line after the last list item or a line with just a dot on the line (`.`). See the doxygen documentation https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/lists.html